# using variable external like searching pattern in awk

Tags: nawk

I have next example of script:

The proposal is to find `ID = 67109AB` inside "file.txt", using an external variable, in this case, it's called: var.
But, when I run script, it doesn't take value of variable like search pattern.

So, someone can help me to know if there is missing something?

Thanks for your help.

```
    fu="/67109AB/"
awk -v var="$fu" '
     var {
        print $0
}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
fu="67109AB"; awk -v var="$fu" '$0 ~ var' file.txt
```